# How to make a JSON with custom fields

Tags: python, json, regex, request

I am not too sure if this is even possible as i was not able to find any exact information on it. I will try to best explain what i would like to do below.

So i am using the requests library to pull information from an API. Once i have this data i use regex to find all matches for a specific piece of information from the json output.

The code i have is:

```
for i in data['resources']:
        if 'id' in i and 'name' in i:
            b = i['name'], i['id']
            k = str(b)
            if  re.findall("'Server-Ownership-\w+', \w+", k):
                matchedOwners = re.findall("'Server-Ownership-\w+', \w+", k)[0]
                j = str(matchedOwners)
                print(j)
```

The output of this code gives me:

```
'Server-Ownership-A', 100
'Server-Ownership-B', 200
'Server-Ownership-C', 300
'Server-Ownership-D', 400
'Server-Ownership-E', 500
'Server-Ownership-F', 600
'Server-Ownership-G', 700
'Server-Ownership-H', 800
```

What i would like to do is somehow reference each server-ownership line as its own so that i can use the ID at the end associated with it to perform a get request for each server. My problem is that i cannot determine a way to call on any of this data. I figured maybe if i could turn it into json and create a 'name' field for the 'server-ownership' part and then an 'id' field for the IDs at the end. Is this even possible or is there a better way to approach this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using a regexp instead of just accessing the dictionary keys directly?

Comment: `if i['name'].startswith('Server-Ownership-'):`

Comment: @barmar thats what i did in my initial get request. where my for loop starts i reference the id key and name key. i need regex because i am returned a lot of data that isn't what i need. So by using regex i am able to only display the "server-ownership" which is what i need. Also, the id key and name key are not together so i needed them lined up side by side for the corresponding server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change what you have written so far. I modified it so that you can have a dictionary for the server owners. As you requested, everything in matchedOwners will be added to a dictionary.

```
server_owners_dict=dict()

for i in data['resources']:
    if 'id' in i and 'name' in i:
        b = i['name'], i['id']
        k = str(b)
        if  re.findall("'Server-Ownership-\w+', \w+", k):
            matchedOwners = re.findall("'Server-Ownership-\w+', \w+", k)[0]
            j = str(matchedOwners).strip().split() # get rid of whitespace and split by comma
            server_owners_dict[j[0].replace('Server-Ownership-','')]=j[1]
```

Comment: now these server owners can change. they will always start with 'Server-Ownership-'. is there any way i can make like a for loop that will automatically detect the name and then print the id? my end goal is to place this info into excel. Such as the server owner name and then the id.

Comment: You can easily just replace out the 'Server-Ownership-' part, like I just edited into my solution.

Comment: sorry for all the questions i just want to get a better understanding of this to expand my knowledge. What exactly does that last line do that will detect the names automatically?

Comment: No worries! Since you explained that the server owners always start with 'Server-Ownership-', we first look for owners matching 'Server-Ownership-', like you did, and then upon making our dictionary we remove the 'Server-Ownership-' part, leaving us only with the names.

Comment: so how would i reference each name automatically one by one to do a get request using the id associated with it? the goal of the script is to run it and have it do everything on its own.

Comment: Simply do ```r = requests.get(url = URL, params = server_owners_dict)```

Comment: The params include the keys which are the owners names, and the values associated with them, which are the ids

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208281/discussion-between-pythonscrub-and-oamandawi).

Answer (score 1):

You can save these as a dictionary and get the value by calling the keys.

```
server_owners_dict = {'Server-Ownership-A': 100,
'Server-Ownership-B': 200,
'Server-Ownership-C': 300,
'Server-Ownership-D': 400,
'Server-Ownership-E': 500,
'Server-Ownership-F': 600,
'Server-Ownership-G': 700,
'Server-Ownership-H': 800}


print(server_owners_dict['Server-Ownership-E'])
500
```

Change the print to a function and return the id to be used in the request.

Comment: can i set the script to automatically make whatever is found in matchedOwners a dictionary?

Comment: also, these server names can change, i am trying not to hardcode them into the script incase they change down the road. They will always start with 'Server-Ownership-'

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put the values in a string and then use a regular expression. Just test `i['name']` directly and use it as a dictionary key.

```
server_owners = {}
for i in data['resources']:
    if 'id' in i and 'name' in i and i['name'].startswith('Server-Ownership-'):
        server_name = i['name'].split('-')[-1] # get A from Server-Ownership-A
        server_owners[server_name] = i['id']
```

This will create a dict like

```
{'A': 100, 'B': 200, 'C': 300, ...}
```

Comment: server_owners = { } will make it a set. You need to use dict().

Comment: My bad! It's even faster to use {}: https://doughellmann.com/blog/2012/11/12/the-performance-impact-of-using-dict-instead-of-in-cpython-2-7-2/